# Using Google maps in an iframe dynamically with javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, iframe

I have an html page (formatted with bootstrap-4 & flexbox) with an iframe in which I would like to place a google map.  I believe I have a credential issue but am not certain.

I construct the following URL and assign it to the src attribute of the iframe in javascript.

https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/view?key=MY_KEY_HERE&center=40.7688825,-73.980176111111&zoom=18

I get the error:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (OK)

The actual frame is filled with:
The Google Maps API server rejected your request. This API project is not authorized to use this API. Please ensure that this API is activated in the APIs Console:

However, I have been to the console and the javascript API is enabled for my key.  I clearly don't understand the message, and would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: See [Error 403](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403), it clearly says the server forbidden the client request. You can refer to the [google map API forum](https://developers.google.com/maps/support/) for more info.

Comment: You are using V1 of maps.  That has been deprecated for years

Comment: I got v1 using cut-and-paste.  Is it no longer possible to use maps through javascript by assigning a url to the iframe's src attribute?

Comment: You need to use Embed API here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide. Also, would need an API key to authenticate your request.